# Site is Unavailable without a VPN Connection but OK with VPN & other Network

Tags: wordpress

I can’t visit my site when I turn the VPN off.But I can visit it when the VPN is ON.
In Operamini,there is build-in VPN. So I turn it ON and I can visit my site. However I can’t visit my site with Google Chrome or Firefox on the same machine. [No VPN is used for Chrome or Firefox]
If I turn OFF the VPN Connection of Operamini, then I can’t visit the site using Operamini. But switching it ON allows me to visit my site without any issue.
It’s informative to mention that when I try to search anything on Google, they tell me , “Our systems have detected unusual traffic from your computer network….. ” and it shows me a Captcha to solve.
I am not using any kind of Security Plugin. I had Wordfence plugin. But it is Not active.
My phone Connected to the same network. But I can’t visit my site with the phone. But when I disconnect it from the network and use Phone Data then I can visit my site.
I am hosting my site in Ubuntu VM on DigitalOcean Droplet.
The error Message shown in Chrome is-
“This site can’t be reached india2bd.com took too long to respond.
Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
Running Windows Network Diagnostics
ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT”

Comment: Any online checker will show that your domain have fatal errors in its DNS configuration: http://dnsviz.net/d/india2bd.com/dnssec/ and https://zonemaster.net/result/eee78115d9674725. You need to fix all of that before anything else.